# Placed Image in Photoshop is larger than actual size, regardless of PPI

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ppi

I'm currently experiencing a weird issue with placing images in photoshop.

I currently am trying to place an png that is 750x1334 and has a ppi of 72. This image has been exported from illustrator.
The photoshop file's image size is 5000x3338 and has a ppi of 240.

When placed, the image becomes 1877x3338. I have the setting "resize image when placed" on so it fits the in the canvas.

When I try to place the same image with a ppi of 240, I get the same exact result.

I first thought that it had something to do with PNG not keeping track of PPI, which is an answer in [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30178/imported-image-is-much-larger-than-it-in-the-original-photoshop-file) question. But then I tried it with jpg and I got the same result.

So what is going on? Is there something wrong with my Photoshop file?

Comment: Turn off "Resize Image on Place"

Comment: That doesn't solve it as it just becomes larger than the canvas.

Comment: What I mean is that with "resize image on place" being turned off, the image size becomes larger than the canvas. It becomes 2500x4447 image with the option turned off (1877x3338 with the option on so it fits the canvas). What I want is that the image will be 750x1334 (The actual size) when I place it.

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining that the placed image is the same size when you are *specifically* telling Photoshop to resize when placed. I also do not understand what you *expect* to occur with that setting active and different sized images are being placed.

A PNG@240ppi will simply be increased in width and height when compared to a PNG@72ppi. If you have `Resize Image When Placed` on, then that increased width and height is changed when you place the image so it fits within the canvas bounds.

Turn off `Resize Image When Placed` and place a 72ppi PNG and a 240ppi PNG... there's a difference.

PNGs (and sometimes JPGs) may not store a PPI setting internally. Instead they merely increase the width and height of the image to accommodate the additional pixels. If everything is resized when placed, it's all going to look the same to you. When you place a 240ppi image it may be reduced, condensing the pixels into a higher resolution. If you place a 72ppi image it may be enlarged stretching the pixels to a lower resolution.

I don't understand why you need things to fit the canvas bounds emphatically. Turn off that setting, place your 240PPi image and then use Free Transform to reduce it to the desired size.

Comment: The reason why I need it to be the same size is because I want to replace a smart object with that image. When I resize that image the warping is too much. I just added a 72ppi and a 240ppi image through place and they both have a resolution of 2500x4447

Comment: The Smart Object information would have been helpful in the question. Open the smart object, by double-clicking the layer thumbnail in the Layers Panel... place your new image **inside** the smart object, save, and close the Smart Object window.